# My solution to a LeetCode problem works fine, until I try to improve it by using a helper function. The argument isn't being returned

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, global-variables

Hey and thanks in advance for the help guys!

So I seem to be having a problem implementing a helper function while trying to solve a LeetCode problem. I've already found a working solution, but when I try to wrap repeated logic in a helper function, it seems the argument isn't being returned.

The problem is to merge two sorted linked lists and return it as a new sorted list. The new list should be made by splicing together the nodes of the first two lists. Here is a link to the problem on LC: https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/

This is my working solution:

```
var mergeTwoLists = function(l1, l2) {
    let dummyHead = new ListNode(0),
        q = l1,
        v = l2,
        curr = dummyHead;
    while (q !== null || v !== null) {
        if (q && v) {
            if ( q.val !== null && v.val !== null) {
                if (q.val <= v.val) {
                    curr.next = new ListNode(q.val);
                    curr = curr.next;
                    q = q.next;        
                } else {
                    curr.next = new ListNode(v.val);
                    curr = curr.next;
                    v = v.next;
                }
            } else if (q.val !== null) {
                curr.next = new ListNode(q.val);
                curr = curr.next;
                q = q.next;
            } else {
                curr.next = new ListNode(v.val);
                curr = curr.next;
                v = v.next;
            }
        } else if (q) {
            curr.next = new ListNode(q.val);
            curr = curr.next;
            q = q.next;
        } else {
            curr.next = new ListNode(v.val);
            curr = curr.next;
            v = v.next;
        }      
    }
    return dummyHead.next;
};
```

So as you can see, the same step is repeated multiple times throughout my solution. Once I tried to handle it with a helper function, it seems there's an issue with the argument `curr` being returned. It always appears fresh each time the function is run by the algorithm.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be appreciated :) Here is the solution implemented with a helper function:

```
var mergeTwoLists = function(l1, l2) {
    let dummyHead = new ListNode(0),
        q = l1,
        v = l2,
        curr = dummyHead;
    while (q !== null || v !== null) {
        if (q && v) {
            if ( q.val !== null && v.val !== null) {
                if (q.val <= v.val) {
                    attachNode(curr, q);
                } else {
                    attachNode(curr, v);
                }
            } else if (q.val !== null) {
                attachNode(curr, q);
            } else {
                attachNode(curr, v);
            }
        } else if (q) {
            attachNode(curr, q);
        } else {
            attachNode(curr, v);
        }    
    }
    return dummyHead.next;
};

function attachNode(curr, value) {
    curr.next = new ListNode(value.val);
    curr = curr.next;
    value = value.next;
    return curr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a mistake with function scope. If you have a function like

```
function f(arg) {
    arg = 'another value';
}
```

then `arg` in the calling scope does not change. The parameter `arg` is a copy of the argument in the calling scope whose value does not change the argument in the calling scope:

```
let arg = 'some value';
f(arg);
arg === 'some value'; // this is true
```

It looks like you are considering this to some extent because you return `cur` from the function but you don't assign the value to anything.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) No, I only recently added the return statement hoping that was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

- We don't have to set the `value` to `value.next` because the lists are already sorted;
- In [Linked List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), just tracking links and connecting them would suffice:

#### Recursive:

```
const mergeTwoLists = function(l1, l2) {
    if (l1 === null) {
        return l2;
    }

    if (l2 === null) {
        return l1;
    }

    if (l1.val < l2.val) {
        l1.next = mergeTwoLists(l1.next, l2)
        return l1;

    } else {
        l2.next = mergeTwoLists(l1, l2.next)
        return l2;
    }
}
```

#### Iterative:

```
const mergeTwoLists = function(l1, l2) {
    const sentinel = {
        val: -1,
        next: null
    };

    let head = sentinel;
    while (l1 && l2) {
        if (l1.val > l2.val) {
            head.next = l2;
            l2 = l2.next;
        } else {
            head.next = l1;
            l1 = l1.next;
        }
        
        head = head.next;
    }

    head.next = l1 || l2;

    return sentinel.next;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for going above and beyond in responding. You've helped me gain a deeper understanding of linked lists.